# Proper way to subset big.matrix

Tags: r, subset, r-bigmemory

I would like to know if there is a 'proper' way to subset big.matrix objects in R.  It is simple to subset a matrix but the class always reverts to 'matrix'.  This isn't a problem when working with small datasets like this but with massive datasets but with extremely large datasets the subset could still benefit from the 'big.matrix' class.

```
require(bigmemory)
data(iris)
# I realize the warning about factors but not important for this example
big <- as.big.matrix(iris)

class(big)
[1] "big.matrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "bigmemory"

class(big[,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")])
[1] "matrix"

class(big[,1:2])
[1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have since learned that the 'proper' way to subset a `big.matrix` is to use `sub.big.matrix` although this is only for contiguous columns and/or rows.  Non-contiguous subsetting is not currently implemented.

```
sm <- sub.big.matrix(big, firstCol=1, lastCol=2)
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem to be possible without calling `as.big.matrix` on the subset.

From the `big.matrix` documentation,

> If `x` is a big.matrix, then `x[1:5,]` is returned as an R matrix containing the first five rows of `x`.

I presume this also applies to columns as well.  So it seems you would need to call

```
a <- as.big.matrix(big[,1:2])
```

in order for the subset to also be a `big.matrix`  object.

```
class(a)
# [1] "big.matrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "bigmemory"
```