# Removing columns from a "big.matrix" gives error: "cannot allocate vector of size 37.6 Gb"

Tags: r, matrix, subset, submatrix, r-bigmemory

I have a large "big.matrix" and I need to remove a few columns from it. It was created from a CSV file (with 72 million rows) using

```
BigMat <- read.big.matrix("matrix.csv", type="double", header=TRUE,
                     backingfile="matrix.bin",
                     descriptorfile="matrix.desc")
```

This successfully loads the matrix into **R** but I do not have enough memory space to create a new object when trying to subset this matrix:

```
BigMatSub <- BigMat[, 5:71]
```

It gave me: **Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.6 Gb**.

Is there any way of the removing columns while without hitting memory limit? I need to have it as "big.matrix" object in the end to use in `biglasso()`.

The matrix is sparse with many zero values.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are using package **bigmemory**. No wonder you could store the full matrix "in the memory" in the first place.

I haven't used **bigmemory** before. But intuitively, if the subset we want to extract is still too large, we still want a "big.matrix" after subsetting, instead of coercing it to a regular dense matrix. The error message you got implies that the usual `"["` does not respect a "big.matrix" object, and attempts to return a dense matrix that is 37.6 GB. Wow! This implies that your "big.matrix" roughly has 75,322,188 rows!

Searching "subset" in the package's PDF manual, I find that you could try:

```
BigMatSubset <- deepcopy(BigMat, cols = 5:71)
```

Interesting, the manual also documents `"["`. But it does not explicitly state if we are going to lose "big.matrix" class and get a regular matrix instead. For verification, you could extract a very small subset:

```
what <- BigMat[1:10, 1:4]
```

and see if `what` is a regular dense matrix.

---

**Update**

Searching "[r] deepcopy" gives only [7 posts (excluding this answer) so far](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+deepcopy). The most relevant one is:

- [Removing columns from big.matrix which have only one value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49959260/4891738).

I also discovered function `sub.big.matrix` when reading those posts. Searching "[r] sub.big.matrix" gives only [2 posts so far (excluding this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+sub.big.matrix), both answered by [Charles Determan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204250), an author of **bigmemory**:

- [Proper way to subset big.matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26495761/4891738)
- [How to efficiently do cross-validation with big.matrix in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33615056/4891738)

I am now convinced that `sub.big.matrix` is a better way to go.

All these posts are tagged with [r-bigmemory](/questions/tagged/r-bigmemory). So I will edit your question to include this tag, too.